# JQuery autocomplete having a suggestion when click AND different suggestions when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to suggest a user an input once he has clicked on the input field, but also I want to keep a list of suggestions when he will be entering letters.

For instance let's say I have this simple code:

```
<script>
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
});
</script>
```

I want to add the feature for the user to have another suggestion when he clicks on the form input let's say "Python.
For instance in this image, one have a suggestion ("Flexible") once we have clicked in the input field:

[image: here]

and then we can have a list of suggestions when we start entering letters:

[image: here2]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what is your `minlength` set to?

Comment: Hey...
Do you want a behaviour such that user selects some suggestion from first autocomplete and then based on his selection, he should see another autocomplete with suggestions linked to first autocomplete selection only?
If this is the case, I made a jsfiddle: Please check if you want this.
http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/765/ 

I will update my answer if you update your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got two understanding from your question, I would like to answer from both the perspectives:

1) default autocomplete on click and see suggestions further on typing.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/768/

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var first = ["ask","always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet","force9", "westerners", "sport"];

    $("#firstHint").on("click", function(){
      $(this).autocomplete("search","");
    });

    $( "#firstHint" ).autocomplete({
        source: first,
        minLength:0,
        select : function(event, ui){
         if(ui.item && ui.item.value){
          alert(ui.item.value);
         }
        }
    });
});
```

**you need to trigger autocomplete on click event of text box and set minLength as 0 for autocomplete.**

2) You want another autocomplete on clicking any suggestion from first autocomplete:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/765/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var first = ["ask","always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet","force9", "westerners", "sport"];
    var second = {
    "ask" : ["to","two","three","too"],
    "one" : ["great","game","gone","going"],
    "tweet" : ["tweeter","twitter","tweety","true"]
    }

    $( "#firstHint" ).autocomplete({
        source: first,
        select : function(event, ui){
         if(ui.item && ui.item.value){
          autoSecond(second[ui.item.value]);
          $(this).addClass("hide");
          $("#secondHint").removeClass("hide").focus();
         }
        }
    });

    function autoSecond(val){
     $("#secondHint").autocomplete({
        source: val,
        select : function(event, ui){
         if(ui.item && ui.item.value){
           alert(ui.item.value);
         }
        }
    });   
    }

});
```

Need to hide first field on selecting first suggestion and show second field where new suggestions will be shown.

Please let me know if any other changes are required. I will modify my answer as required.

New change as per your requirement:
http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/771/

Comment: Thank you for this answer but unfortunately you missed the point, what I want is **1)** having the word "Python" appears when I click on the input **2)** having a list with other words than "Python" appear when I start entering some words. I think I did not explain correctly, my bad.

Comment: Perfect! Much Thanks